# What sort of company should I contract with to replace a deck on a roof?

Tags: roof, deck

I have a small 10x4' roof deck that I am concerned needs to be replaced. The wooden deck material is rotting some, as the area is pretty shaded and it's generally wet here (so probably replace the wood with some synthetic material). In fact, the wooden door to this deck rotted out at the bottom and I had it replaced last year. The guy who replaced it mentioned that when he took out the threshold it appeared that the builder did not put the appropriate roofing material down under the deck (might have said it was just house wrap). It also does not look like the drip edge was done correctly - I went out in a rainstorm recently and water was coming from under the edge and out from behind some of the siding under this area, which I think would explain why the siding under the area is in such bad shape and the paint is peeling again less than a year after being redone.

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/kaHPFUh)

What sort of company should I contact about this? Should I call a deck company? A roofing company?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need *both* trades, or you need a general contractor who has both on staff or can subcontract one or both.

The roofer would replace all roofing and flashing and install any additional protective layers to support the deck.

The carpenter would remove the current deck and build the new deck with support contact with roofing done according to the roofer's specifications. The carpenter would also make any repairs to damaged framing the roofer may find.

Having done such jobs I can attest that a carpenter with a little roofing experience and a roofer with a little carpentry experience will both struggle to get this fairly complex task done properly and reliably. Of course, the roofer and the carpenter can also be a single person if that person is well versed in both trades.